# how move view up when keyboard appears in iPad?

Tags: ipad, uikeyboard

When the iPad virtual keyboard appears, it covers some of the textfields in my View. Is there a way to move the ViewController up when the keyboard appears?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to place your objects on a `UIScrollView`, then when the keyboard appears, you can use `scrollRectToVisible:`.

```
[scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

Comment: i'm kind new on this, do you have a simple example about how do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have wrote this code for one of my Application.

It automatically detects the Position of the TextField and Scroll the baseView Accordingly.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}



- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    CGPoint temp = [textField.superview convertPoint:textField.frame.origin toView:nil];
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){

        if(up) {
            int moveUpValue = temp.y+textField.frame.size.height;
            animatedDis = 264-(1024-moveUpValue-5);
        }
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        if(up) {
            int moveUpValue = 1004-temp.y+textField.frame.size.height;
            animatedDis = 264-(1004-moveUpValue-5);
        }
    }
    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        if(up) {
            int moveUpValue = temp.x+textField.frame.size.height;
            animatedDis = 352-(768-moveUpValue-5);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(up) {
            int moveUpValue = 768-temp.x+textField.frame.size.height;
            animatedDis = 352-(768-moveUpValue-5);
        }

    }
    if(animatedDis>0)
    {
        const int movementDistance = animatedDis;
        const float movementDuration = 0.3f; 
        int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
        [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
            baseViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(baseViewController.view.frame, 0, movement);       
        }
        else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

            baseViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(baseViewController.view.frame, 0, movement);
        }
        else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

            baseViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(baseViewController.view.frame, 0, movement);
        }
        else {
            baseViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(baseViewController.view.frame, 0, movement);
        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Comment: very useful indeed. Tried it. Works perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Do change ValayPatel code "if" statement to `if(animatedDis>0 || !up)` for condition when up = NO, else the shifted view is always at previous position.

Comment: I believe that the original code intended animatedDis to be a property, and therefore the > 0 value will be retained when finishing editing, causing the views to animate to their original position.